# Another approach to get rid the warning banner

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I had two improper questions which were deleted by the community about a year ago, and I'm shame about it. Now there is a banner warn me about "not been well-received."

I saw someone commented "Took me month **answer** a hell lot questions getting upvoted to lift that ban off me." I want a confirmation from a moderator because the answer I saw is "fix old questions, ask new high quality questions."

Comment: @chrisneilsen The problem is I'm not able to fix those question

Comment: @chrisneilsen yes, this type of question asked so many time, but what the solution if I can't edit it? Ask more questions with more up votes?

Comment: The point is you haven't hit the Q ban _yet_, but if you keep posting poorly received posts you _will_.  So improve the quality of your future posts

Comment: @chrisneilsen So I ask better questions, the banner will gone, am I right? Can I do it by answering others question?